# Reference a COM Library at Compile time In a Late format

Tags: vb.net, binding, reference, compile-time

I have an unusual scenario with a third party library I'm required to use.

The library is packaged with the last 3 versions of the product. Normally this would mean for my software to work with all of them, I would reference the oldest version of the three (at compile time) and it would work for all three versions.
This is not the case however, which means I would need to compile for each version seperately if I wanted to use a proper "reference" to the library.

My first alternative is to convert all my very type specific code to use late bound format
Eg.

```
Dim item as new documentItem          ' this is not real code, just pseudo...
```

to

```
Dim item as object = createobject("clsid.documentItem")
```

I **Absolutely HATE** doing this late bound format and losing the compile time checking. Especially since this library is huge and very complex.

A second approach does not seem to be possible, which is to install all 3 products and reference all the libraries seperately.
It seems they "Tried" to make it compatible and the Unique Identifiers of the COM components are the same. Unless someone can explain how to import the same library 3 times in the same DLL with overlapping CLSID's and Names. (This would also mean a large ammount or code modification to use different wrappers for each target application)

**Question:**
Does anyone know of any other way of dealing with this scenario? My objective is to retain the Compile time checking and auto-complete. Possibly some way to have the interop library created on the client side.

**Update:**
I had already done all the access to this libary through my own wrapper DLL to consolidate functions to one project. So for the time being I copied the entire wrapper library I had created to a new DLL and used regular expressions to do a mass converstion to late bound format. Using the same Root Namespace I can switch between them easily. In this format I can do the bulk of my development against one version that is using Strict Compiler rules. As changes are done there and proven I move a copy to the Late Bound Library and remove all the specific references. So far this seems to be the best way to deal with it.
To publish I switch the library to the late bound version.
So far this seems to be the a good way to keep as much compile time checking in the program as possible with what is so far a fairly small amount of additional work, though it is annoying as well.

Comment: There isn't.  Putting a prerequisite on the box and insisting the client updates is the only reasonable alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure is the case as well. Unfortunately I MUST support the multiple libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem.

What I did was register each version of the COM component and rebuild my project. This caused .NET to create the Interop Library for the COM component.

I then copied the new "interop.component.dll" to a sub directory where I rename it to "Version1.Component.dll"

Repeat those step until all 4 Interop Libaries are created such as

- "Version1.Component.dll"
- "Version2.Component.dll"
- "Version3.Component.dll"
- "Version4.Component.dll"

Mark each as an Embedded resource in the Primary DLL

Set Copy Local = FALSE for the COM Library in the References. This now makes the Interop Library not found when .NET tries to load it on demand when the compoents class is requested in code.

In a Module in the Primary DLL I add the following code...

```
Public WithEvents CurDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain

Private Function AssemblyResolve(sender As Object, args As System.ResolveEventArgs) As System.Reflection.Assembly Handles CurDomain.AssemblyResolve
Dim resourceName As String = New Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name).Name & ".dll"
Dim curAsm As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
If resourceName.EndsWith("Component.dll") Then
    'supply the correct resource
    resourceName = ver & "." & resourceName  ' ver is set to the currently desired version.
    Using stc As IO.Stream = curAsm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
        Dim bt(CInt(stc.Length - 1)) As Byte
        stc.Read(bt, 0, CInt(stc.Length))   'get to a new byte array
        Return Reflection.Assembly.Load(bt) 'load actual assembly from decompressed stream data.
    End Using
End If
End Function
```

The above code is triggered whenever .NET cannot resolve a DLL which allows you to manually supply it.

Now all 4 slightly different versions of the interop library will work with whichever version of the COM component is registered on the machine.